# Genitive Case - soft question

Tags: словоупотребление

I'm extremely confused...
Why is the following sentence wrong?

> Брат Адама любит Москвы

According to the rules, to form the genitive case for feminine nouns one should replace **a** with **ы**, but clearly that's not the case here... why is that?

Comment: Verb "любить" takes genitive object only when negated (and it works only with some nouns). Брат Адама не любит Москвы.

Comment: even in negative, genitive would sound weird here. It more used with some very vast categories. Like "does not like big cities" or "...streets of Moscow". Rather than narrow specific object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the following sentence wrong?

Because you must use the Accusative case here. I.e. "*Брат Адама любит **Москву***".

As @AlexVB noted, in a *negative* sentence you may use any of two cases, that is, both "*Брат Адама не любит **Москву***" (Acc.) and "*Брат Адама не любит **Москвы***" (Gen.) are OK. But in a positive sentence there's no alternative.

The root of a mistake is probably the fact that Genitive and Accusative do coincide for animated nouns. But note that "*Москва любит **брата Адама***" is grammatically the Accusative case, although the Genitive is spelt absolutely the same.